# Unexpected results with StreamReader.ReadLine()

Tags: c#

I am currently testing an application that stores the user's contact details in a file. This information is also stored in a local compact database as the primary method - storing their details in this file is a backup in case those details are lost.

The file I'm using for testing has my personal data in it, so I hope you understand that I have replaced the lines with placeholders! The structure of this file is as follows (minus the first line):

```
File: 


Business Name
Mr.
Joe
Bloggs
user@email.com

Address Line 1
Address Line 2
City
Postcode
Country        




07777123456
```

Below, I have some code that reads this file and stores each line as a variable. The structure of the file will never change, hence the very simple code:

```
public static bool RestoreBusinessTable(out string title, out string busName, out string mobileNumber, out string firstName, out string lastName)
        {    
            string email = "", referral = "", contactNo, addressLine1 = "", addressLine2 = "", city = "", postcode = "", country = "", district = "";
            busName = null;
            mobileNumber = null;
            firstName = null;
            lastName = null;
            title = null;

            try
            {
                if (!File.Exists(fileName))
                    return false;
                StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fileName);
                string work;
                work = sr.ReadLine();   // Empty line
                work = sr.ReadLine();   // Empty line
                busName = sr.ReadLine();
                title = sr.ReadLine();
                firstName = sr.ReadLine();
                lastName = sr.ReadLine();
                email = sr.ReadLine();
                referral = sr.ReadLine();
                addressLine1 = sr.ReadLine();
                addressLine2 = sr.ReadLine();
                city = sr.ReadLine();
                postcode = sr.ReadLine();
                country = sr.ReadLine();
                work = sr.ReadLine();  // Empty line
                work = sr.ReadLine();   // Empty line
                contactNo = sr.ReadLine();
                district = sr.ReadLine();
                mobileNumber = sr.ReadLine();
                sr.Close();
                // Add to database here
                return true;
            }
            catch
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

When running this code, I noticed that `busName`, `title`, `firstName`, and `lastName` all had a value of `07777123456`. The data looked like this:

```
07777123456
07777123456
07777123456
07777123456
user@email.com

Address Line 1
Address Line 2
City
Postcode
Country




07777123456
```

I do not have any asynchronous processes or threads which are writing to the file at the same time. Could anyone shed any light as to what is happening here, and why the first four lines would appear as the mobile number?

Comment: What you say cannot happen using the code you posted. How do you call this code and how do you print the variables? Also try using a data transfer object instead of countless `out` parameters.

Comment: Looks like you're repeatedly overwriting `work`. It will only take the last value you assign to it.

Comment: Oh sorry, that's not one of your `out`puts.

Comment: @RichardTowers good suggestion, but its a placeholder variable that is only used for the empty lines in the file. The work variable never actually gets assigned a proper value.

Comment: Can't see how that would happen based on the code you've posted, are they messed up at sr.Close()?

Comment: @CodeCaster But it *is* happening using the code I posted. I have gone through it line by line, and the variables are re-assigned halfway through the function.

Comment: Please extend the code with the surrounding method and the class.

Comment: You don't need the `work` variable at all. It's fine to call `ReadLine()` and completely *ignore* the return value.

Comment: I think your "edit" is very misleading - you *can* write to `out` parameters like that - if my answer is correct, then it would be clearer to say "if the caller requests something silly, then something silly will happen"...

Comment: Why the close-vote? This question fits stack overflow's Q&A format perfectly. I'm fed up with people down-voting and close-voting because the OP doesn't have the knowledge and experience that others may have. This is a site intended for learning, and that is exactly what I am doing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to do that would be for the calling code to supply the same variable's/field's address to the various `out` parameters:

```
string tmp;
RestoreBusinessTable(out tmp, out tmp, out tmp, ...);
```

Here the same address is passed in each location, so no matter whether your code assigns to `title`, `busName`, etc it is *writing to the same actual location*.

Since `mobileNumber` is assigned last, the value assigned for the mobile number will be the value that appears for all the values.

The key point here is that `title`, `busName`, etc are not each a *reference to a string* - because of the `out` (or `ref`, equally) they are each a *reference to a reference to a string*.

Comment: I wasn't really following you until you wrote `they are each a reference to a reference to a string.` - that suddenly made the issue very clear to me. Thank you!